# Calculate stock remaining using 2 lists

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

Not sure if this is possible, its quite a simple thing I'm sure, but struggling to work out how to achieve it.

I have two lists, a stock list and a customer list.  In the stock list I have the following fields:

Item Name

Item ID (just a unique number)

QTY (Initial quantity in stock)

QTY remaining

In the Customer list I have:

Customer Name

Item purchased (This is a lookup of the Item ID field in the Stock list)

QTY purchased

Now all I want to do is some kind of count function that takes the QTY purchased and subtracts it from the QTY and displays the result in the QTY remaining field so I know how many we have left in stock. Obviously the QTY purchased must be linked in some way to the Item purchased so it knows which Item ID to subtract from.

Surely that's got to be possible?  Or is there an easier way I can do it in SharePoint?

Thanks in advanced all!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a workflow would be the best option.  Write the workflow against the Customer list and for each new item make the changes to the related stock item.

Comment: Thanks Dave, but how on earth do I do that?  I'm new to all this!
Cheers

Comment: You will either need to use SharePoint Designer or a third party solution such as Nintex Workflow.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I have created a workflow in SP designer, but im new to this and its not working.  Can i send you a screenshot somehow of what I have done, maybe you can suggest why it is not working?

Comment: I am far from being a workflow expert - best advice I can give is to do it in steps and get each step working before you do the next bit.

Answer (score 0):

Attach a workflow to your Customer list and set it to start automatically upon item creation.

The workflow should look like this:

[image]

As you can see, I've created 2 variables of type Number, InitialQTY and QTYRemaining.
You need to set InitialQTY to equal the value of the current QTY remaining in stock, like this:

[image]

Then, you calculate the difference between InitialQTY and the QTY purchased, and assign the result to the QTYRemaining variable.

The last step is to update the Stock list QTY Remaining field by setting it to the value of the QTYRemaining variable.